# R: Creating a funcion that capitalizes the first n elements of a vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function (v, n) where v is a vector of letters/ words, and n is an integer number. This function should return the same vector but with the "n" first elements in capital letters.

So far I've made this:

```
capital <- function(v, n){
  c <- v[n]
  return (toupper(c))
}
```

But this function only returns the "n" element in capital letters, not all the first "n" elements. Also it doesn't return the rest of the chain.

So, if we have v <- c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta") and n <- 2. My funtion returns:

```
[1] "BRAVO"
```

But I would like that it returns:

```
[1] "ALPHA" "BRAVO" "charlie" "delta"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to subset the `vector` based on the sequence of 'n' and assign back by applying `toUpper`

```
i <- seq_len(n)
v[i] <- toupper(v[i])
```

-output

```
v
#[1] "ALPHA"   "BRAVO"   "charlie" "delta"
```

---

In the OP's function, the `return` is not assigning based on the index

```
capital <- function(v, n){
    stopifnot(n <= length(v))
    i <- seq_len(n) # // create a sequence from n
    v[i] <- toupper(v[i]) # // apply toupper based on the index
    return(v) # // return the updated vector
  }
```

-output

```
capital(v, n)
#[1] "ALPHA"   "BRAVO"   "charlie" "delta"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is possible to add any condition to avoid that "n" is higher than the elements in v?

Comment: @Jusep Sure, we can use `stopifnot`

Comment: @Jusep added the condition

Comment: Thanks! That's useful. But using stopifnot i can't execute the function if  "n" is higher than the elements in v. It could be possible to make that, if this happens, all the elements are converted to capital? Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you again!

Comment: @Jusep THe condition is the if you do `capital(v, 10)` it will stop executing.  If you need to return the original object, you can have an `if/else`

Answer (score 1):

We can try:

```
capital <- function(v, n){
  c1 <- v[1:n]
  c2 <- toupper(c1)
  c3 <- c(c2,v[(n+1):length(v)])
  return (c3)
}
capital(v =  c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta"),n=2 )
```

A full explanation would be:

1. In `c1` we choose the number of words.
2. In `c2` we capitalize them.
3. In `c3` we merge with the original vector.
4. Finally, we return.